# Why does the measurement tool not snap to vertices?

Tags: measurement

I want to know the width of an edge. So I tried to use the measurement tool and select two vertices. But to my surprise, it did not snap. Why doesn't the measurement tool snap to the vertices when I enable the snapping to vertices option?

See also:
https://youtu.be/aIFSPqxgq0s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to enable snapping.
The Measure tool only snaps to vertices and edges.

*Notice the bottom status bar gives you all available commands*
[image]

Comment: snapping is already on why should I have to hold control?

Comment: Hi @Unknow0059 :). In earlier versions (this post is 3 years old) mesaure tool did not snap unless you held 'Ctrl'. It does now, so this answer is obsolete for current versions :).

Answer (score 1):

You may have encountered a known Blender bug. You cannot snap to INTERNAL points, even if you can see them with X-Ray or by hiding part of the object.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers provided, you can also easily see the length of an edge if you tick *Edge Length* at the bottom of the *Overlays* list. Then select the edge to see its length.

[image]